# Problem with HDMI external monitor

Tags: display, hdmi

I am using Elementary OS 5.0 with Linux 4.15.0-46 and GTK+ 3.22.30 on a Dell G7 with GeForce GTX 1050.

When I turn the computer on with HDMI plugged in, everything goes well. However, when I plug the HDMI when the computer is on, the computer screen goes black with some noisy colors and the monitor doesn't detect anything.

What could I do to track and workaround this problem?